# jQuery read country from cookie and put in Google variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, variables, google-maps-api-3

I'm having a hard time with my Google Maps script. It is designed to read the country of the user stored in a cookie and then put that into the Google Maps auto-suggest variable, so it only suggests places from their country.

This is the code I have been working with:

```
  autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input[0], {
    types: ["geocode"],
    componentRestrictions: {
      country: "uk"
    }
  });
```

Then I created this:

```
// SET COOKIE FOR TESTING   
$.cookie("country", "us");

var country_code = $.cookie('country');
if (country_code) { options.componentRestrictions= { 'country': country_code }; }
var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
```

I cannot seem to work out how to implement the code above into my code here without it breaking or reading it: http://jsfiddle.net/spadez/5dqHg/8/

**TL;DR**

How do I make it so my [current code](http://jsfiddle.net/spadez/5dqHg/8/) reads the cookie and puts it in the "country component restrictions" variable for Google Maps auto-suggest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try creating an `options` object and updating that with what is found in the cookie:

```
var autocompleteOptions = {
    types: ["geocode"],
    componentRestrictions: {
        country: "uk"
    }
};

var country_code = $.cookie('country');
if (country_code) { 
    autocompleteOptions.componentRestrictions.country = country_code; 
}
var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, autocompleteOptions);
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5dqHg/9/)**: You should note that your link for the jQuery.cookie plugin isn't valid in jsFiddle. GitHub doesn't serve it up with the correct mime-type, so the file won't be interpreted as javascript